# type error while multiply using float value

Tags: python, input, typeerror

I am trying to multiply user input by float value. Below is my code

```
user_input = input("enter your float number:-")
raw = user_input * 2.2
print (raw)
```

but getting following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pravin/Documents/python_app_build_project/section_5/test1.py", line 3, in <module>
    raw = user_input * 2.2
          ~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
i want to convert user_input by 2.2
```

Comment: You need to cast user string input to float by using `float(input("enter your float number:-"))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`user_input` is of type `str`, you can check it by doing this:

```
user_input = input("enter your float number:-")
print(type(user_input))
```

You shoud convert `user_input` to numeric type before performing multiplication, for example `float(user_input) * 2.2`

But be prepared to catch an exception if user enters something other than a float number, for example, a word - automatic conversion to float will fail in that case.

Answer (score 0):

you should change the type of input data to string like this:

```py
user_input = float(input("enter your float number:-"))
raw = user_input * 2.2
print (raw)
```

hope this helps :)